# How to meake file upload control with resume in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

How to make ASP.NET file upload control with resume, without file size limitation and with secure connection?

Any idea?

Comment: Is a client side helper object a possibility in your scenario, if not this is non-starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split file to small part. 
Upload each part separately. If connection broke, just re upload last part and continue with other.
After all parts are uploaded, just combine all parts on server in one file.

Comment: What are you going to use client side to split the files up??